# How to interpret confusion matric for Extreme learning machine ? why it has decimal points in it?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

[image: Confusion matrix for Extreme learning machine algorithm]

ELM for phishing URL detection.
Dataset is divided into 70/30. 30% is for testing.
Dataset size: 11,000 Entries.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion matrix shows the percentage of observations that fall into a combination of the actual and the predicted value. These percentage add up to 100% row-wise (0.3419 + 0.6581 = 1). This means that of all observations that had the label 'Phishing', 34.19% were correctly classified as 'Phishing' and 65.81% were incorrectly classified as 'Legitimate'.

Answer (score 0):

$34\%$ of "phishing" messages were classified as "phishing".

$66\%$ of "phishing" messages were classified as "legitimate".

$1\%$ of "legitimate" messages were classified as "phishing".

$99\%$ of "legitimate" messages were classified as "legitimate".